# How to pull certain values from dic with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to pull out some specific values from this output:

```
{'GigabitEthernet': [{'name': '1', 'ip': {'address': {'primary': {'address': '192.168.200.200', 'mask': '255.255.255.0'}}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ospf:router-ospf': {'ospf': {'authentication': {'key-chain': 'sv-10599'}, 'message-digest-key': [{'id': 1, 'md5': {'auth-key': 'cisco'}}], 'network': {'point-to-point': [None]}}}}, 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '2', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}, {'name': '3', 'shutdown': [None], 'mop': {'enabled': False, 'sysid': False}, 'Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet:negotiation': {'auto': True}}]}
```

Ideally I would like to get the following values:

GigabitEthernet
1
192.168.200.200
255.255.255.0
GigabitEthernet
2
Shutdown

```
for device_interface_type in device_config['Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native']['interface']:
        print(device_interface_type)
```

returns GigabitEthernet, but I can't seem to get the 'name', 'address' or 'mask'. Can someone with a little more knowledge on this help me and also point me to a good location on where I can learn more about how to handle these situations with python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple loop will get what you need

```
for device_interface in device_config["GigabitEthernet"]:
    print('GigabitEthernet')
    print(*device_interface.items(), sep='\n')
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-items-method/

Answer (score 0):

use the `get` function. For instance, with the following dictionary:

```
test_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 'two', 'c': 3.0}
test_dict.get('c', 'default-value')
```